# Output matrix rows in sets of two

Tags: matrix

I've got a Matrix field with say 20 rows (could be 21).

I want to output those rows within  but i want 2 rows in each .

Any idea how to accomplish this with the switch tag in Matrix? I'm trying some weird and wacky stuff but nothing is working as i want.

So markup i would want is:

---

```
<div>
{row 1 content}
{row 2 content}
</div>
```

---

```
<div>
{row 3 content}
{row 4 content}
</div>
```

---

```
<div>
{row 5 content}
{row 6 content}
</div>
```

---

```
<div>
{row 7 content}
</div>
```

And here is my current template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="downloads" dynamic="no" disable="pagination|member_data|categories|category_fields" orderby="random"}
    <div>
{dl-downloads}

        <h4>{dl-download-title}</h4>
        <p>{dl-download-desc}</p>
        {switch="|</div><div>"}

{/dl-downloads}
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Matrix `{switch}` variable will work for this. Try:

```
<div>
    {matrix_field}
        {row_count}<br>
        {switch="|</div><div>"}
    {/matrix_field}
</div>
```

Which will output:

```
<div>
    1
    2
</div>
<div>
    3
    4
</div>
<div>
    5
    6
</div>
<div>
    7
</div>
```

Just replace `{row_count}` in my example with whatever Matrix column short names you would want to use.

Comment: Hmm, no, that's not working. Still getting one <div>{stuff}</div> for each row. It's not doing it for 2 rows.

Comment: Strange. It works fine in my test template. Can you post your template code? Or maybe a simplified test case that isn't working for you?

Comment: I've edited the original question with my current template code based on your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Oh goodness me, i just realised, there are multiple channel entries with one matrix row in each, not the other way round! Your code works fine in the channel loop! What a idiot i am!! Cheers Alex!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Funny how sometimes just posting template code can make you realize the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get it. You want to output all your rows and wrap all sets of two rows with a div?

Will something like this do the trick, or am I mising something?

```
{matrix}
    {if "{switch='one|two'}" == "one"}<div class="row">{/if}
    ... something ...
    {if "{switch='one|two'}" == "two" || "{row_count}" == "{total_rows}"}</div>{/if}
{/matrix}
```

Comment: I've added a better code example for you in the initial question :)

Comment: Yep my solution would work as well for what you are trying to accomplish. I tend to find it more readable but that's just me.